UserId from AuthenticationStateProvider keeps on changing on each refresh
I'm currently creating a Blazor web application (client + server). User authentication is managed using ASP.NET Core Identity with a SQL Server database.
The issue I face is the value of _userId keeps on changing with each refresh, so I'm unable to track the state of the user using the same.
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    user = authState.User;
    var _userId = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
}

Update :
public class ApplicationAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly SecurityService securityService;
    private ApplicationAuthenticationState authenticationState;

    public ApplicationAuthenticationStateProvider(SecurityService securityService)
    {
        this.securityService = securityService;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

        try
        {
            var state = await GetApplicationAuthenticationStateAsync();

            if (state.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(state.Claims.Select(c => new Claim(c.Type, c.Value)), "myapp.Server");
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
        }

        var result = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

        await securityService.InitializeAsync(result);

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<ApplicationAuthenticationState> GetApplicationAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if (authenticationState == null)
        {
            authenticationState = await securityService.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        }

        return authenticationState;
    }
}

}

You have to be persisting to the client some way, how are you doing that?

@GHDevOps Please see update.

I'm using InteractiveAuto with OIDC and this has been working for me: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/blob/main/8.0/BlazorWebAppOidc/BlazorWebAppOidc/PersistingAuthenticationStateProvider.cs
